# recibir un parámetro pasado al formulario

Tags: php, html

Buenas os informo de mi problema:
en php tengo un div que muestra una función que muestra los usuarios

que es esta:

```
    function VerUsuariosRegistradosEnTabla(){
    $link =Conectarse();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM usuarios ORDER BY id DESC";
    if ($resultado = $link->query($sql)) {
        echo "<table class='table table-striped'>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Usuario</th>";
        echo "<th>Contraseña</th>";
        echo "<th>Estado</th>";
        echo "<th>Grupo de usuarios</th>";
        echo "<th>fecha de registro</th>";
        echo "<th>Nombre</th>";
        echo "<th>Apellido 1</th>";
        echo "<th>Apellido 2</th>";
        echo "<th>Correo</th>";
        echo "<th>Imagen</th>";
        echo "<th>Cambiar contraseña</th>";
        echo "<th>Opciones</th>";

        echo "</tr>";
        while($fila = $resultado->fetch_assoc()) {
            //echo "Idacceso: " . $fila['id'] . "IdUsuario: " . $fila['idusuario'] . "Nombre: " . $fila['nombre'] . "Fecha: " . $fila['fecha'] . "<br>";
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $fila['usuario'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo "**";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $fila['estado'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $fila['id_tipo'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $fila['fecharegistro'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $fila['nombre'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $fila['apellido1'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $fila['apellido2'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo $fila['correo'];
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<img src=" . $fila['imagen']." border ='0' height='42' width='42'>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            echo "<a href='#FormularioCambioPass' data-toggle='modal'>Cambiar password</a>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "<td>";
            //echo "<a href='aa.php?a=$row[0]' value='Seleccionar' class='btn btn-default' style='background-color: #04B404'>";
            //echo "<a href='#FormularioEditarUsuario?idusuario=$fila[0]' data-toggle='modal'>Editar</a>";
            echo "<a href='#FormularioEditarUsuario?idusuario="."jose"."' data-toggle='modal'>Editar</a>";
            echo "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";
        $resultado->close();

    }
    mysqli_close($link);
}
```

el caso es que a esta función la llamo desde un fichero html y va bien
el problema lo tengo al cargar el toggle='modal' que se encuentra en el mismo fichero  que llamo esta función, la llamada la hace bien pero no consigo recibir el parámetro que le pongo
la idea es pasar el id del usuario pero por más pruebas que hago no lo consigo

luego en el modal tengo lo siguiente:

```
<section class="bg-light" id="formularioEditarUsuario">
        <div class="modal fade" id="FormularioEditarUsuario" role="dialog">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                        <h4 class="modal-title">Editar Usuario</h4>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">                        
                        <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="administracion.php" enctype='multipart/form-data'>
                            <fieldset>
                                <legend>Modifica los datos necesarios</legend>
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label class="col-md-8 control-label" for="Nombre">Usuario</label>  
                                    <div class="col-md-8">
    <input id="UsuarioNuevo" name="UsuarioNuevo" type="text" placeholder="Usuario" class="form-control input-md" required>
                                    </div>
                                    Diferentes opciones<p>
                                    Cambio de contraseña<p>
                                    cambio de datos personales<p>
                                </div>
                                </fieldset>
                                                                <input type="submit" value="Enviar" class="btn btn-default">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Guardar</button>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Elimiar Usuario</button>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

el modal lo abre bien pero no consigo recibir el parámetro que le paso con nombre idusuario

alguien me puede ayudar por favor??

Gracias

Comment: Tu pregunta no es clara. ¿Envías los datos aquí: `echo "<a href='#FormularioEditarUsuario?idusuario="."jose"."' data-toggle='modal'>Editar</a>";`?  ¿Qué es `FormularioEditarUsuario`, es una URL amigable que recoge el parámetro `idusuario=ose` o algo así? Por otra parte debo decir que el uso de modales es una práctica que comienza a ser obsoleta. Hoy día se tiende más a interfaces gráficas integradas en las cuales pues mostrar/ocultar por secciones lo que necesites. Es más práctico, más profesional, más fácil y mejora la experiencia de usuario. Las actualizaciones se pueden manejar con Ajax.

Answer (score 0):

no entiendo bien tu pregunta, pero por lo que entiendo debes modificar esta linea

```
echo "<a href='#FormularioEditarUsuario?idusuario="."jose"."' data-toggle='modal'>Editar</a>";
```

a

```
echo "<a href='#FormularioEditarUsuario?idusuario=".$fila['usuario'];' data-toggle='modal'>Editar</a>";
```

de igual manera, no especificas bien si tu id es "usuario" o "id_tipo".
Espero te ayude!

Comment: Gracias, eso ya lo tengo
ahora mismo está comentado por si lo que me estaba fallando era tomar el parametro pero no:


            //echo "<a href='#FormularioEditarUsuario?idusuario=$fila[0]' data-toggle='modal'>Editar</a>";

el id es id de usuario en la base de datos se llama id, 
el problema está en que aunque ponga jose  no lo coge, al recibirlo, no me llega nada, no se porqué.

gracias

Comment: Podrias explicar mejor que es lo que te falta hacer? Intentare ayudarte

Comment: Gracias, lo que me falta es recibir el parametro en el formulario: FormularioEditarUsuario
 que no se si por estar en otro fichero diferente o por que no lo estoy haciendo bien nunca me toma ese dato

gracias

Comment: echo "<a href='#FormularioEditarUsuario?idusuario=jose' data-toggle='modal'>Editar</a>";
intenta de esa manera, si te lo coge es porque algo esta haciendo mal en el php, de lo contrario esta algo mal en el formulario.
Tienes algun medio de contacto? Por ejemplo correo o algo como discord, mucho mejor

Comment: Gracias pero, no, lo sigue mostrando en blanco: id usuario selecionado: quizá el problema esté en la forma de recibir el parámetro, lo tengo de la siguiente forma:       $idusuario = GET['idusuario'];
      
      echo "id usuario selecionado: ".$idusuario;
el caso es que como la URL no cambia al ser un modal, creo que me viene por ahí el problema.. es posible??
gracias

Comment: Puede ser, intentaste probarlo en una pestaña externa? Osea fuera de un modal

Comment: si, y de esta forma si me funcionó

Comment: Podrias cambiar la ventana modal por un pop up¿?

Comment: Gracias por la ayuda pero, un POP UP no me vale porque después viene un formulario para captar más datos y tengo entendido que da problemas con los POP UP

Comment: he cambiado un poco el codigo con una nueva funcion:  $id= $fila['id'];
   echo "<a href='#FormularioEditarUsuario?idusuario=jose'onclick='PoneridUsuarioenGlobal($id)' data-toggle='modal'>Editar</a>";

en esta funcion se encuentra: function PoneridUsuarioenGlobal($id){
 $_SESSION['idusuario'] = $id;
 global $MISDATOS;
}

y ya me muestra algo... pero siempre me muestra 1

Answer (score 0):

Alguien me podría ayudar? creo que pasar el parámetro por sesion no es la mejor manera, ademas de que no me funciona como yo deseo

una variable global o algo así?

gracias

Answer (score 0):

el problema estaba en que al ser un PHP no carga parámetros nuevos, entonces hay que meterle alguna función con otro lenguaje, encontré esto en JS y me va de lujo, lo pongo por si alguien le ayuda

Un saludo a todos

```
<script>
    $('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
        var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
        var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
        // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
        // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
        var modal = $(this)
        //idusuario
        // modal.find('.modal-title').text('New message to ' + recipient)
        //modal.find('.modal-body input').val(recipient)
        modal.find('#idusuario').val(recipient)
    })
</script>
```